# How to improve perfomance of SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, query-performance, qsqlquery

I have the following query in Stored Procedure:

```
UPDATE  dbo.CRM_tblActivityStore
SET StoDateChngFlg = CASE 
             WHEN x.STAGE_STAD <> x.ACTSTR_STAD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    (SELECT CASE 
WHEN sd.stad = '00000000' THEN '12-31-2049' ELSE CONVERT (DATE, sd.stad) 
END AS STAGE_STAD,
                CONVERT (DATE, tas.StoDateSTA) AS ACTSTR_STAD,
                tas.StoActivityNbr,
                sd.Proj_Code,
                sd.OrderNbr,
                sd.FileNbr
         FROM   [SCM Server].[OrdrMgmt].dbo.STAGE_StageData AS sd
                INNER JOIN
                dbo.CRM_tblActivityStore AS tas
                ON sd.Proj_Code = tas.StoProjCode
                   AND sd.OrderNbr = tas.StoOrderNbr
                   AND sd.FileNbr = tas.StoFile) AS x
        INNER JOIN
        dbo.CRM_tblActivityStore AS tast
        ON tast.StoActivityNbr = x.StoActivityNbr
           AND tast.StoProjCode = x.Proj_Code
           AND tast.StoOrderNbr = x.OrderNbr
           AND tast.StoFile = x.FileNbr;
```

Some more information that might help:

[SCM Server].[OrdrMgmt].dbo.STAGE_StageData - has more than 2,000,000 rows
dbo.CRM_tblActivityStore - has more than 5,000,000 rows

None of these tables is indexed and no Primery key.

This one take more than 3 hours.

How drasticley can it be improve to add index?

Any other ideas how to improve it?

Thanks,

Ilan

Comment: Yikes!!! Tables with no clustered indexes are called heaps. You have a couple of pretty good sized ones. There is little to no chance of improving performance here without some structural changes to your tables. You need a primary key and then you will need to add some indexing. Without more detail it is hard to know what those might be.

Comment: first deal is to update statistics
second - indexes

Comment: I noticed that u use table from linked server in join. Not a good idea (imho).  If U use SQL Server 2008+ - try to use cross apply

Comment: As DimaSUN mentioned, the performance issue is just as likely to be your linked server as your lack of indexes. Finding yourself in this situation (using linked servers, no indexes) is not a good indication.

Answer (score 1):

As David says, adding indexes on the join columns will improve the response time for this query. However, that doesn't address the underlying issue of why these tables don't have primary keys. A primary key uniquely identifies each row in a table. Are you /really/ sure your data model allows duplicate rows? If so, are you sure that fits your business needs? Is there another, perhaps better, way of approaching the problem you're trying to solve.

Rules to consider:
1 - each row uniquely identifiable (primary key)
2 - each column in the row is related to the primary key
3 - each column is only to the primary key

You might need to break these tables into multiple tables. Consider carefully what each table is trying to describe and the relationship to the other tables. Do not try to make any one table do more than is allowed by its primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When optimizing queries I always start by using the

> Include Actual Execution Plan

option in SSMS, under the Query menu option.

You will then get a trove a info as to how to optimize your query. It will even give you the actual index creation script it thinks you need to add.

Good luck with this. I'm sure you can bring down this query to a few minutes.

Comment: why the down vote? Without recreating his DB it will be hard to improve on his query. So directing him to the proper tools could certainly help him.

Comment: I don't see a reason to down vote it.
This is the only answer that try to help to improve the query it self and not only the indexes and Primery Key which I know I have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your database will be much improved by adding some indexes. In the query you provided, you have some joins which would benefit from the associated columns being indexed.
I.e. sd.Proj_Code = tas.StoProjCode and sd.OrderNbr = tas.StoOrderNbr and sd.FileNbr =tas.StoFile

So long as the fields you are trying to match are the same data type, indexing will drastically improve your query times.

Try indexing some columns then check what the planner is trying to do to see if you should change what is indexed - single or multiple column indexes, primary keys, etc